# Sqoop Syntax error, unexpected tIdentifier

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, sqoop

I'm trying to load MySQL table to hbase using sqoop. I'm using the below command but it is showing unexpected tIdentifier error. Please help.

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/manideep --username root --password cloudera --table sample --hbase-table H_LOAN --column-family CD --hbase-row-key id -m 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following command has worked for me to achieve hbase table import in Sgoop:

`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/manideep"  --username <username> --password ****** --table <mysql-table-name> --columns "column1,colmn2,column3"  --hbase-table <hbase-table-name> --column-family <hbase-table-column-family> --hbase-row-key <row-key-column-name> -m 1`

If the solution does not work, please post the exact issue (exception details) you have faced.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was running the command under hbase shell earlier. I tried running outside the shell and it worked.